# is it possible to find a close-form of this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, closed-form

So my problem is: given $x_{n+1}=(x_{n})^3+(x_{n})^{1/3}$ and $x_0=1$, prove or disprove the following statement: it is possible to find a closed form of this.

I am very confused how to do this: should I proceed by induction? I know how to find the rate for how fast this thing increase( but not in close form)-- I want to know if this is even possible to write in closed form...

Comment: do we start by showing $x_{n+1}=(x_{n})^2+(x_{n})^{1/2}$ and $x_0=1$ this has a closed formula? I am really confused if it is even possible..

Comment: It is very difficult to show there is no closed form for something, so unless you are taking a very high level class there almost certainly is a closed form. So look for a closed form, and if you find it, prove that the formula works.

Comment: um I was researching online about a closed form on 2nd order recursive form, but now I have no luck yet. I am now considering a geometric approach, which was taking vector and angles into consideration. I will post my further progress here.

Comment: Maybe you can find a closed form using Laplace transform.